# Custom Npm Registry breaks npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I an facing issues while using my orgn. registry.

Lets say my orgn `registry` url is:

```
demo.registry.jrdy:8080/repo/repo.proxy/
```

Initially I used npmrc, **this worked!**

```
proxy=http://<some-proxy-with-creds>
https-proxy=https://<some-proxy-with-creds>
strict-ssl=false
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Now I plan to move to an internal registry (I need to *publish* private repos)

**Altered** npmrc as:

```
strict-ssl=false
registry=https://demo.registry.jrdy:8080/repo/repo.proxy/
always-auth=true
no_proxy=*.jrdy
```

This is where issues begin!

Lets say I execute command(or any other install command for that matter)

```
npm i -g http-server
```

Output:

> ```
> cb() never called
> After investigating logs
> Error 502 notresolvable https://demo.registry.jrdy:8080/repo/repo.proxy/http-server
> ```

In addition if I navigate to https://demo.registry.jrdy:8080/repo/repo.proxy/http-server on **browser** the file is available!

---

**Edit:** Also tried force clearing cache, manually deleted npm contents under `~/AppData/Roaming/npm`

I am sure I am doing something wrong with npmrc, but dont know what

Kudos in advance!
Varun A

Comment: what is the content of package-lock.json ?

Comment: Hi @Hendra,  unfortunately could not share the file since its on my office machine and the bank constraints are, well you know...
Said that i am installing file globally so not sure if .lock is created...

Comment: Yep, lock shouldn't apply in the case of a global install. Is it the `no-proxy` line maybe messing you up - depending how you're network is configured you may need the proxy in place to access that site

Comment: @PeterReid Thanks for inputs. I tried dropping it, no success. Also tried discarding `always-auth` and added proxy/http-proxy properties. No success.

Also tried ping and telnet on `demo.registry.jrdy` works with charm